# Rails use sass to import all css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I use rails and bootstrap by using this [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

I've moved `application.css` to `application.scss`, so I can't use `*= require_tree`.

There are bunch of css files in `assets/stylesheets`, how can I import them?

I tried following ways but all of these seems not work.

```
@import "freelancer";
@import "freelancer.css";
@import "freelancer.css"!force;
```

### Update

I recently found out that there is a way to `import` all file, check [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#features)

> When in Rails, there is a special import syntax that allows you to glob imports relative to the folder of the stylesheet that is doing the importing.

```
@import "mixins/*" will import all the files in the mixins folder
@import "mixins/**/*" will import all the files in the mixins tree
```

Comment: This might only be misspelled in your post but you have _applocation.scss_, it should be **application.scss**.

Comment: I typed wrongly in question, but it's correct in project. Thanks, I've modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scss being a superset of css, you can just change your .css extension to .scss, it will still work in the same way.

Then you can require them like this, and it should work:

```
@import "freelancer";
```

Comment: So, the only way is to change every `.css` to `scss`?

Comment: I try and it work perfectly, but I mean it's a little weird, if some gem only provide css file (some gem need to type *=xxx in application.css), how to import them?

Comment: seems like [you're not alone](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/556), but the issue is still discussed apparently